# Save session after application restart

Tags: python, tornado

I am building a web application based on Tornado web framework and I MongoDB to store the data. I create a session id for each user entered the site, and store some data in a attribute of a Handler class. Moreover I store session data in MongoDB.

Each time a make some changes in the code, I need to restart my app, and it creates new sessions. How do I save sessions across application restarts and do not ask user to log in again?

Comment: If you want the data to be persistent, store it in a database. Tornado doesn't provide anything like this on its own, so you'll have to write code to handle all of this yourself.

Comment: I store it in database. But I do not know how to retrieve the data after restart, because the will be new session ids after it.

Comment: I also store session id in cookies, but it is updated after server restart. So I stuck here

Comment: Tornado doesn't even *have* sessions, so you're using some code that you wrote to do this. Without that code, there's no way to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks I've got it. There was a stupid mistake in my code.